# can't map ec2 instance port to docker container's port

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I use ECS to deploy a docker container to ec2 instance.

My ECS task definition:

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "postgraphile-container",
      "image": "019384571013.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/test-repository",
      "memory": 500,
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 5000,
          "containerPort": 5000,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "volumes": [],
  "memory": "900",
  "cpu": "128",
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "family": "postgraphile",
  "taskRoleArn": ""
}
```

When I ssh into my ec2 instance, I do see the container running. When I attach to running container, I can see that my node app is running on port 5000, I successfully get a response with `curl localhost:5000`. When I exit from the container and try to do the same in the ec2 instance, I get an error: `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`.

I also got a docker container ip with `docker inspect` and tried to do the same `curl <container ip>:5000` and got this error: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.2 port 5000: Connection refused`

Am I missing anything? Still can't access the service running inside the container

Comment: Are you connecting to `localhost:5000` from the EC2 instance itself? Or are you trying to connect to the EC2 instance port 5000 from a remote machine? If the later, make sure that you have port 5000 enabled from the remote IP Address using [Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html). By default, EC2 instances assume least privilege, so no access is enabled remotely by default.

Comment: I created an inbound rule for port 5000 in my admin panel. But it's not the case now, I'm trying to access my service inside the container from inside the ec2 instance. I ssh into my ec2 instance as i described above, and i'm not able to access the service

Comment: What happens if you try from your instance, but using the container IP instead of `localhost`? `docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <container_name_or_id>`

Comment: It's not able to use your task definition to reproduce task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the reason: my nodejs app inside the container was listening the connections from localhost by default. I configured it to accept requests from any source, and everything worked fine with the above config.